# Offer optimised algorithm to work with timestamped values

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#. Need to optimise counting positive and negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713323/c-need-to-optimise-counting-positive-and-negative-values)

I need to maximize speed of the following functionality:

- a. a value comes in. value has 2 properties - int value and long timestamp in ticks.
- b. need to count previously stored values which are younger than 1ms (from the current).
- c. need to count negative and positive separately.
- d. i only need to know if there are either 10 neg or pos values. i dont need to keep any other knowledge of the values.

me thinks - to implement 2 ring arrays for pos and neg separately, replacing expired with 0 keeping track of pos.neg counts as they come.

any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible that the values will be received out of order, i.e. first a younger, then an older value?

Comment: Your requirements are confusing. What do you mean in part (c)?

Comment: one option is to add a field that will store the count of data having timestamp less than 1 ms than all the previous data. The advantage would be that you will not need to perform O(N) operation on addition of a new data, but you can achieve the same result, by comparing against the previous value

Comment: @staven. yes, sorry had to say that. the timestamps might get out of order.

Comment: @skizz the actual task is to set a certain variable to -1 when neg count reaches 10 or 1 if pos reaches 10. this is why i count them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining 2 buffers to keep the positives separated from the negatives sounds like a pain and inefficient.

You could instead have a single buffer with all the values, and use `std::accumulate` to count up the positives and negatives.  If you start with a collection of all the tuples (each of which has an age and a value), you could begin by sorting the collection according to age, finding the last element that is <= 1 ms old, and then using `accumulate` from `begin()` to that point.  Here's some code that demonstrates that last bit:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Counter 
{
    Counter(unsigned pos=0, unsigned neg=0) : pos_(pos), neg_(neg) {};
    unsigned pos_, neg_;
    Counter& operator+(int n)
    {
        if( n < 0 )
            ++neg_;
        else if( n > 0 )
            ++pos_;
        return * this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    vector<int> vals;
    generate_n(back_inserter(vals), 1000, []() 
    {
        return (rand() / (RAND_MAX/40)) - 20;
    });

    Counter cnt = accumulate(vals.begin(), vals.end(), Counter());
}
```

If sorting the collection by age and then searching the sorted results for the last eligible entry sounds too ineficient, you could use `for_each_if` instead of `accumulate` and simply iterate over the whole collection once.  `for_each_if` isn't part of the Standard Library, but it's [easy enough to write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234482/using-stl-to-find-all-elements-in-a-vector/234556#234556).  If you don't want to muck about with writing your own `for_each_if` that's fine, too.  You could simply tweak the accumulator a bit so that it doesn't accumulate elements which are too old:

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Tuple
{
    int val_;
    unsigned age_;
};

struct Counter 
{
    Counter(unsigned pos=0, unsigned neg=0) : pos_(pos), neg_(neg) {};
    unsigned pos_, neg_;
    Counter& operator+(const Tuple& tuple)
    {
        if( tuple.age_ > 1 )
            return * this; 

        if( tuple.val_ < 0 )
            ++neg_;
        else if( tuple.val_ > 0 )
            ++pos_;

        return * this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    vector<Tuple> tuples;
    generate_n(back_inserter(tuples), 1000, []() -> Tuple
    {
        Tuple retval;
        retval.val_ = (rand() / (RAND_MAX/40)) - 20;
        retval.age_ = (rand() / (RAND_MAX/5));
        return retval;
    });

    Counter cnt = accumulate(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), Counter());
}
```

Comment: thank you. but you need to consider that accumulate will be called as much as 10 times per ms... and the vector managment will eat up all of it. as tuples will not be nicely added in the beginning. they are coming fast and i need to insert/place them first

Comment: Ah, well that's a different problem, then.  It was not really clear by my reading of your OP that the incoming data is not to be cached.

Comment: Well now, hold on.  Your question's title says "timestamped values **in an array**."  Where is that array?  You can just `accumulate` off of that.

Comment: the array will take all the ram on the server if i accumulate it. i need to discard older values. but in principle you are probably right

Comment: `accumulate` doesn't make copies of the elements in the array.

Comment: I am sorry John. the title *was* wrong. i meant array which will be part of the solution. in your code it is your vector. i dont have array. the data is coming from network and cant be stored in memory......

Answer (score -1):

I would store the values in a min-heap keyed by timestamp - so the youngest values are at the top of the heap.  The integer value is auxiliary data at each node.  You could then implement the counting with a recursive function that traverses the heap.  You'd pass the running total of negative and positive back up the recursive call.

It would look something like this, in Python-like pseudocode with types:

```
def young_pos_and_neg(Time currtime, HeapNode p):
    if (p is not None and currtime - p.time < 1):
        posleft, negleft = young_pos_and_neg(p.leftChild())
        posright, negright = young_pos_and_neg(p.rightChild())
        totpos = posleft + posright
        totneg = negleft + negright
        if (p.intValue < 0):
            return totpos, totneg + 1
        else:
            return totpos + 1, totneg
    else:
        return 0, 0
```

If you call this on the heap root before inserting the new value - but with the new value's timestamp as the `currtime` argument - you will get a count of each.  It may not be the fastest possible way, but it's pretty simple and elegant.  In C++ you could replace the tuple return value with a struct.